# Update depending on field length on another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, switch-statement, sql-update, case

I need to update a column in a table depending on a column datalength in another table.

Tables:

```
SOURCE:
Item_Group    Name
------------|-----------
1000        | Joe
1001        | Jill
1002        | Joanna
222222      | James
333333      | John

DESTINATION: 
Item        | Group     | Person
------------|-----------|----
1000        | 000001    |
1001        | 000002    |
9998        | 222222    |
9999        | 333333    |


UPDATED DESTINATION: 
Item        | Group     | Person
------------|-----------|----
1000        | 000001    | Joe
1001        | 000002    | Jill
9998        | 222222    | James
9999        | 333333    | John
```

Update should be based on `Item_Group`'s datalength. If datalength is 4 update should be done based on Item, If  datalength is 6 update should be done based on Group.

I have two separate querys, which i believe, do function.

```
UPDATE table_dest
SET Person = a.Name
FROM table_source a, table_dest b
WHERE a.Item_Group = b.Item
AND DATALENGTH(a.Item_Group) = 4
GO

UPDATE table_dest 
SET Person = a.Name
FROM table_source a, table_dest b
WHERE a.Item_Group = b.Group
AND DATALENGTH(a.Item_Group) = 6
GO
```

How is this done in a single query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `apply` :

```
UPDATE dt 
     SET dt.Person = s.Name
FROM table_dest dt CROSS APPLY
     ( VALUES (dt.Item), (dt.[Group]) 
     ) dtt(ItemGroup) INNER JOIN
     table_source s
     ON s.Item_Group = dtt.ItemGroup;
```

Comment: `Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 65
Ambiguous column name 'ItemGroup'.`

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #tempSOURCE(Item_Group INT,NAME VARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO #tempSOURCE(Item_Group,[NAME])VALUES(1000,'Joe')
INSERT INTO #tempSOURCE(Item_Group,[NAME])VALUES(1001,'Jill')
INSERT INTO #tempSOURCE(Item_Group,[NAME])VALUES(1002,'Joanna')
INSERT INTO #tempSOURCE(Item_Group,[NAME])VALUES(222222,'James')
INSERT INTO #tempSOURCE(Item_Group,[NAME])VALUES(333333,'John')

CREATE TABLE #tempDESTINATION(Item INT,Destgroup INT,Person VARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO #tempDESTINATION(Item, Destgroup, Person) VALUES(1000,000001,'')
INSERT INTO #tempDESTINATION(Item, Destgroup, Person) VALUES(1001,000002,'')
INSERT INTO #tempDESTINATION(Item, Destgroup, Person) VALUES(9998,222222,'')
INSERT INTO #tempDESTINATION(Item, Destgroup, Person) VALUES(9999,333333,'')

SELECT * FROM #tempSOURCE

SELECT * FROM #tempDESTINATION



UPDATE b 
SET b.Person= CASE WHEN a.Item_Group=b.Item THEN a.Name ELSE 
              CASE WHEN  b.Destgroup=a.Item_Group THEN a.Name END END 
FROM #tempSOURCE a inner join #tempDESTINATION b
ON a.Item_Group=b.Item
OR  b.Destgroup=a.Item_Group


SELECT * FROM #tempDESTINATION
```

[image]

**Note:-** here i'm using.. in #tempDESTINATION Destgroup column name instead of Group ..because..Group is reserved key word...

here i'm using join ..instead of checking datalength of column..you will get your output

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
UPDATE b SET PERSON=nAME
FROM #tempDESTINATION B 
cross apply ( 

    select * from #tempSOURCE A where a.Item_Group = b.Item and DATALENGTH(a.Item_Group)=4
    UNION
    select * from #tempSOURCE A where a.Item_Group = b.Destgroup and DATALENGTH(a.Item_Group)=6
) Name1
```